# Firefox input field history not saved

Tags: jquery, firefox, jqgrid

I am trying to reproduce a bug, but I can not make it. The problem is that my `Firefox` (3.6.16) would not save the data I enter in the `input` field. 
I have a scrollable grid using `jqGrid` with a filtertoolbar. The grid is constructed as follows:

```
function radio(value, options, rowObject){
    var radio = '<input type="radio" value=' + value + ' name="radioid" />';
    return radio;
}


jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid({
    url: '$content.getURI("myURI")' + '?userId=$userId&pageNo=0&locale=' + '$locale',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5'],
    colModel :[
        {name:'name', index:'field', width:'8%', search:false, align:'center', formatter: radio, editable:false, sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'name1', index:'field1', width:'23%', sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'name2', index:'field2', width:'23%', sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'name3', index:'field3', width:'23%', sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'name4', index:'field4', width:'23%', sortable: false, resizable:false}
        ],
    width:'768',
    height: 500,
    pager: '#pagerDiv',
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: $rowNr,
    rowTotal: 500,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    loadComplete: loadCompleteHandler,
    ignoreCase: true
    });
});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
                        stringResult: true,
                        searchOnEnter: false });
});
```

I have "Remember search and form history" enabled in the `Options` menu. I have tried it in safe-mode with all plugins and extentions disabled, and still it would not save any data typed in the `input` field. I have also tried pressing an `Enter` after each keyword (since that would normally cause FF to save the data in history ) but that would not change anything. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Firefox saves form input data unless the form is actually submitted. jqGrid is using Ajax to send the form so it is never submitted in the traditional sense.

Comment: If that is the case then check your Firefox versions are exactly the same. If so then you may have a buggy install or a simple restart of your machine might help ;-)

Comment: We have the same version, restart did not help. I have also tried with other FF versions, but still not working.

Comment: I am out of ideas I am afraid.